# parsing JSON object with Jquery problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I am trying to parse the following bit of json with Jquery so far I can get everything out of the results that I want apart from one crucial piece of information the performance tags.

Each json result is wrapped in an event tag and then within this there is info like time and date etc formatted in the following way

```
"location": {
                "lng": -0.1187418,
                "city": "London, UK",
                "lat": 51.4681089
            },
            "start": {
                "time": "19:30:00",
                "datetime":"2010-02-16T19:30:00+0000",
                "date": "2010-02-16"
            },
```

I have managed to loop through this and parse it to html. However there is one set of tags for 'performance' that are formatted differently.

```
"performance": [{
                {
                    "artist": {
                         "uri": "http://www.songkick.com/artists/288696-vampire-weekend",
                         "displayName": "Vampire Weekend",
                         "id": 288696,
                         "identifier": [{"mbid": "af37c51c-0790-4a29-b995-456f98a6b8c9"}]
                    }
                    "displayName": "Vampire Weekend",
                    "billingIndex": 1,
                    "id": 5380281,
                    "billing": "headline"
                }
            }],
```

now in my for loop i am running the following code which displays the performance information in the console.

```
var events = data.resultsPage.results.event;
for (var i = 0, l = events.length; i < l; i++) {

console.log(events[i].performance); }
```

However when i try to go into the structure like i have been with the other elements I get returned undefined i.e

```
console.log(events[i].performance.displayName);
```

Do I have to do this in a different way because of the use of the [ ] brackets in the performance tag in the Json?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that really **exactly** what the JSON looks like?  Because if so, it's syntactically incorrect.  The "performance" property is defined as an array, but the contents are not valid JSON. The only things that can follow an "{" are "}" or a string, and "performance" above starts with two successive "{" characters.

Comment: Also, just to be pedantic: what your code here is doing is not really "parsing".  That's what happens when the JSON code turns the string into the JavaScript object(s).  This is more like "traversing" or something.

Comment: To add: use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSONs.

Comment: I just copied this out of the returned json "performance":[{"artist":{"identifier":[{"href":"http:\/\/api.songkick.com\/api\/3.0\/artists\/mbid:7c158ea8-c0aa-410e-bdc1-20bba9759577.json","mbid":"7c158ea8-c0aa-410e-bdc1-20bba9759577"}],"uri":"\/artists\/277711-cinematic-orchestra?utm_source=2251&utm_medium=partner","displayName":"The Cinematic Orchestra","id":277711},"billing":"headline","displayName":"The Cinematic Orchestra","id":16815661,"billingIndex":1}]

Comment: Oh please, edit your own question to update your response, don't add those pieces of code in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you posted is not exactly what your JSON looks like (because what's posted has a syntax error), the "performance" attribute is an array of objects. To get at the "displayName", therefore, you'd need to know which element of the "performance" array you wanted. You'd then access it by index.

```
console.log(events[i].performance[j].displayName);
```

(assuming you looped through the "performance" array with the variable "j".)

Comment: So do I have to do a loop within my events loop then?

Comment: Yes, because "performance" is itself an array.  I guess each "event" can have more than one "performance"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate your returned JSON object [here](http://www.jsonlint.com/), I guess there is some issue with the JSON output..

Comment: I did this using the json return from the following link
http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?apikey=API_KEY&artist_name=The%20Cinematic%20Orchestra

and it said it was valid??